# How to disable the splash screen on Ubuntu 20.04 on shutdown (not on power on)

Tags: boot, 20.04, plymouth, debug

I want to turn off the splash screen when shutting down, but I can't find anything that talks about disabling the splash screen when shutting down.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?